# Postfix, when using transport - status=bounced (mail for [app01.domain.com] loops back to myself)

Tags: postfix

I got 2 servers, running behind a loadbalancer, which is connectable though the hostname: mail.domain.com

These 2 servers, are both configured as myhostname = mail.domain.com (which is the lb hostname)
I do this because i want my servers to be seen to the outside world, as 1 server.

1 of these servers (app01.domain.com), i use as my mailbox server, since shared storage/replication is not an option, so what i do, is when a mail is hits app02.domain.com, i try to force an transport to app01.domain.com where the mailbox is stored.

So, i have example.com with MX to mail.domain.com.

And i guess that the problem is, that the mx, is the same as myhostname, but is there a way to force it anyway?

hope it all makes sence.

Variables:

> mydestination = mail.domain.com, localhost.domain.com, localhost
>
> mydomain = domain.com
>
> myhostname = mail.domain.com
> mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
>
> myorigin = $myhostname